# How to exclude a tag by a surrounding tag

Tags: html, css

```
<body>
    <acctctrls>
        <a href="http://www.some-link.com/">Link inside acctctrls tag</a>
    </acctctrls>
    <a href="http://www.some-link.com/">Link outside acctctrls tag</a>
</body>
```

I want the <a> tags inside the acctctrls tag to follow this css:

```
a
{
    color: #C20000;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight:600;
    text-align:center;
}
```

I want the <a> tags outside the acctctrls tag to follow this css:

```
a
{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-style: normal;
    color: #D0D0D0;
}
a:hover
{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-style: bold;
    color: #EEEEEE;
}
```

Comment: Any reason why you have that tag? Why not just have those tags have some specified `class`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
acctctrls a {
    color: #C20000;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight:600;
    text-align:center; 
}
```

Comment: ... I can't click the accept as answer button... That's stupid.

Answer (score 0):

did you try:

```
acctctrls a{
    color: #C20000;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight:600;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the inside links, just change the selector to: `acctctrls a, acctctrls a:hover` and specify it after the outside code.

Comment: Yep - The others are partially right, but you have to remember that a:hover affects *every* `<a>` unless you specify a more specific style for it.

Answer (score 0):

```
   a {
    // rules for outer tags
   } 

   acctctrls a {
     // rules for a's within acctctrls
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your styles to:

```
a
{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-style: normal;
    color: #D0D0D0;
}
a:hover
{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-style: bold;
    color: #EEEEEE;
}

acctctrls a
{
    color: #C20000;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight:600;
    text-align:center;
}
```

From [CSS Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html)
When you supply more than one tag name then by default CSS will perform the styling on the last tag when it is a descendant of the tags prior to it.

I know that link is for CSS2, but the same should hold true for CSS3 as well.

Answer (score 0):

Leave the second a, and a:hover rulesets and increase the specificity of the first to take of the links within `<acctctrls />`.

```
acctctrls a {
   color: #C20000;
   font-size: 12px;
   font-weight:600;
   text-align:center; 
}
```

However, as kei said, it would probably be better to use a standard element with a class or id. Otherwise, you'll need to use a JavaScript shiv (e.g. document.createElement('acctctrls')) for IE to recognize your CSS for this element.